# Unable to render - resolver could not resolve to a file

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to setup module structure for my Zend project, and this is an error I am getting. I do not understand why Renderer looking for this path **"online-field-evaluation/online-field-evaluation/index"** . Is there some problem with Camel notation in Zend ? Thanks.

```
Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException

File:

    C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php:499

Message:

    Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "online-field-evaluation/online-field-evaluation/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file

Stack trace:

    #0 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
    #1 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
    #2 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
    #3 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
    #4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #5 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(471): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #6 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
    #7 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(347): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #8 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #9 C:\dev\xampp\htdocs\OnlineFieldEvaluation\public\index.php(25): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
    #10 {main}
```

**Here is my module.config.php:**

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'OnlineFieldEvaluation\Controller\OnlineFieldEvaluation' => 'OnlineFieldEvaluation\Controller\OnlineFieldEvaluationController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                    'onlinefieldevaluation' => array(
                            'type'    => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/onlinefieldevaluation[/][:action][/:id]',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'onlinefieldevaluation\Controller\onlinefieldevaluation',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
    ),      
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'onlinefieldevaluation' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**And here is my Module.php**

```
<?php

namespace OnlineFieldEvaluation;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1: here is the image of my project structure : **

[image]

Comment: Have you created an index view for your controller? I think it's trying to render a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes. I just edited the post adding the project structure. It is strange for me that it is looking for hyphen separated path "online-field-evaluation/online-field-evaluation/index"

Comment: That's how the default template resolver works. See the docs here -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#controllers-and-view-models and in particular the example given of `As an example, the controller Foo\Controller\BazBatController with action “doSomethingCrazyAction”, would be mapped to the template foo/baz-bat/do-something-crazy.`. The same convention applies to the module name. For the above example if the module had been named `FooBar` the template path would be `foo-bar/baz-bat/do-something-crazy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on your config.php you wrote

```
    'invokables' => array(
        'OnlineFieldEvaluation\Controller\OnlineFieldEvaluation' => 'OnlineFieldEvaluation\Controller\OnlineFieldEvaluationController',
    ),
```

But you call

```
'defaults' => array(
       'controller' => 'onlinefieldevaluation\Controller\onlinefieldevaluation',
       'action'     => 'index',
),
```

change by this

```
'defaults' => array(
       'controller' => 'OnlineFieldEvaluation\Controller\OnlineFieldEvaluation',
       'action'     => 'index',
),
```

and change the folders names of your view script to lowercase like

```
view
  online-field-evaluation
     online-field-evaluation
```

Comment: internally keys are lowercased without special chars, so that wouldn't even matter ;) It's just the view-folder-names that he did wrong.

Comment: Strange that renderer is using different naming convention for the view and src forders.